# Multiple Google Adwords onClick tracking events in a single page?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

We have 2 buttons on our page and we want to track the amount of clicks (aka conversions) for each button. I have placed both scripts for each tracking, but it seems that the onClick action for each button itself (the code emebed as part of the link) is the same. Currently Google Adwords is registering one but not the other.

Source of page: **view-source:http://hudsonspine.com**

**This code is not registering:**

```
<!-- Google Code for Healow Conversion Conversion Page
In your html page, add the snippet and call
goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
chosen link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  goog_snippet_vars = function() {
    var w = window;
    w.google_conversion_id = 1037734564;
    w.google_conversion_label = "4WXBCKnSrm0QpKXq7gM";
    w.google_remarketing_only = false;
  }
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
  goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]&gt; */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

**This code is registering:**

```
<!-- Google Code for Zocdoc Conversion Conversion Page
In your html page, add the snippet and call
goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
chosen link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  goog_snippet_vars = function() {
    var w = window;
    w.google_conversion_id = 1037734564;
    w.google_conversion_label = "eAKpCJ3Jrm0QpKXq7gM";
    w.google_remarketing_only = false;
  }
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
  goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]&gt; */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

**Within these links are the onClick functions for each "button" we want read the conversion for:**

```
<a onClick="goog_report_conversion('https://www.zocdoc.com/practice/hudson-spine-and-pain-medicine-3699')" class="button_ color big" title="ZocDoc" href="https://www.zocdoc.com/practice/hudson-spine-and-pain-medicine-3699" target="_self"> ZocDoc </a>

<a onClick="goog_report_conversion('https://www.healow.com/apps/practice/jonathan-kuo-md-8333')" class="button_ color big" title="Contact Us" href="https://www.healow.com/apps/practice/jonathan-kuo-md-8333" target="_self">Healow</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to track the two different conversions with Google Analytics event-Tracking. You can link your Analytics to your AdWords Account and import the the Conversions.

This would look like this: ga('send', 'event', 'Button-A', 'Click', 'Conversion-A', '1');